# Get post thumbnail in specific size

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

```
 $image  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_id() ), 'images_posts' );
```

This code shows Post Images in the original size, but I want to show thumbnail in 160x213 pixel that I have in images folder. How can i do this?

Comment: The Code Reference explains how to do this. You can pass the desired image size into the function as an array. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/

Comment: i saw this article but its very complicated. can u edit my code to show 160x213 pixel thumbnails? it exists in wp images folder

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to add custom image size using `add_image_size`, so when you upload new image using media uploader it will create thumbnail of that size which you assign for image. in `add_image_size` $crop parameter If false, the image will be scaled (default), If true, image will be cropped to the specified dimensions using center positions. in your active theme's functions.php for add custom image size.

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'images_posts', 160, 213, true ); //(cropped)
}
```

After that when you add new image it will create new size of thumbnail then you can use that Image size identifier parameter.

```
$image_data  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_id() ), 'images_posts' );
$image_src = $image_data[0];
```

Comment: i have thumbnails already i think 5 size of per image are in image folder in server. i just want to change showing showing original size to thumbnail size in 1 area of my website. you say i should add just "$image_src = $image_data[0];" this? cause when i have thumnbail it means function is available. yes?

Comment: try using size in array. wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_id() ), array('160','213') );

Comment: tnx ! it worked ! perfect